# Master(Formview)/Detail(Gridview) c# Example

Tags: c#, gridview, formview

Does anyone have an example of a formview with a gridview inside the EditTemplate using c#?
The datasource of the gridview is a datatable.

When setting the dt datasource I get the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
Gridview gv1 = (Gridview)fv1.FindControl("gv1") as GridView;
DataTable dtH = gv1.DataSource as DataTable
dtH = hist.Fetch(acct,dt);
```

Thanks

Comment: One suggestion: you don't need the GridView cast it can just be: Gridview gv1 = fv1.FindControl("gv1") as GridView;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Gridview gv1 = fv1.FindControl("gv1") as GridView;
if (gv1 != null)
{
  DataTable dtH = gv1.DataSource as DataTable
  dtH = hist.Fetch(acct,dt)
}
```